# fixed position of button above image

Tags: css

I have a problem with my webpage. I placed a button on top of an image inside a scrollable `<div></div>`, and this `<div></div>` is inside the `<td></td>` of the table. The button on top of image has the following CSS styles:

```
border:none; 
background-color:transparent;
color:#FFF;
z-index:101;
top:2px;
background-image:url(count.png);
background-size:40px;
width:40px;
height:40px;
padding:0 15px;
font-size:16px;
margin-left:-5px;
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
```

Now the problem is when I scroll down, the button stays on the same position. What I want is when I scroll down the button hides on top together with the image at the same position. How can I make this? Any help would be so much appreciated.

jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnpKj/)

Comment: without your html.... - place your button inside holder for both image and button and then change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;`

Comment: Add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please.

Comment: I have already tried position:relative, but the problem is the button was at the bottom of the image, I want the button to be on top of the image, on the top left part.

Comment: the container of image and button has no CSS styles. Only the buttons has css so I can place it on top of the image.

Comment: You need to create position:relative class definition for parent div containing image and create position:absolute class definition for the button div inside that parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you might be facing is something like positioning. You are position the image `position: relative` to the div, Not the image. If you wrap the image in a `div` and then set the position then it will go up too.

However, that is only the issue, try using something like:

```
<div class="image-div>
  <img src="src_to_file.png" alt="photo" />
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

You can use this as the css:

```
.image-div {
position: relative;
}
.button {
position: absolute;
}
```

Also make sure that `.image-div` is not the main or parent div, as if it is! The button will float over it, but if the div `.image-div` is the child, it will slide (scroll).